# With jQuery 'draggable', the text wraps for some reason when colliding with container. Why? and how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a page where there is a task list on the left and many boxes (one for each employee) on the right so I can dispatch all the tasks quickly.

I don't know if it is relevant, but I use Bootstrap. Here is my list's markup :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">Tasks</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body panel-body-table">
            <div id="Unassigned_1" style="margin-left:0px">Task 1</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_4" style="margin-left:10px">Task 1.1</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_8" style="margin-left:20px">Task 1.1.1 Some long name so I can test</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_9" style="margin-left:20px">Task 1.1.2</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_5" style="margin-left:10px">Task 1.2</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_8" style="margin-left:20px">Task 1.2.1</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_9" style="margin-left:20px">Task 1.2.2</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_2" style="margin-left:0px">Task 2</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_3" style="margin-left:0px">Task 3</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_6" style="margin-left:10px">Task 3.1</div>
            <div id="Unassigned_7" style="margin-left:10px">Task 3.2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the javascript (I'm just begining this page, so the 'drop' code is not there yet)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div[id^="Unassigned_"]').draggable({ helper: 'clone', containment: '.page-content-wrap' });
    });
</script>
```

For some reason I don't know, if I drag any task (such as the one with the long name) to the right, the text wraps when it "hits" the right border of the panel, then when I pass the border with the cursor, the item follows, but it is still wrapped.

Does anyone know why it does that? Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: would you be able to set this up in a fiddle so we can help you better?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it the best I can.

Comment: The text wraps as the plugin calculates the space available and adds `margin-left` to the dragging element. Not sure what is the exact thing you want to fix. If you need the element to stop dragging after the cursor passes the panel border then you need to add `position:relative` to `.panel-body`

Comment: Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/7fw86pvk/

Comment: @anpsmn I need to drag the element and drop it in a box on the right. Ideally, it should stay as close as possible to the original appearance (1 or 2 lines) and not be 10 lines high when at the right of the list. Thanks for your explanation though.

Comment: You can use the classes `.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-dragging ` and set the width like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7fw86pvk/4/)

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Also, I had to add a z-index to be sure the helper stays on top of everything while being dragged. Thanks a lot. Now, I'd like to mark your comment as the answer, but I can't because it's a comment on the original. (I'm new to StackOverflow, maybe I'm missing something obvious)

Comment: Cool. I have added it as an answer. You can't mark a comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix a width of the dragging element using classes `.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-dragging`

```
.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-dragging {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #888;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7fw86pvk/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! If someone wants to see a more "complete" version, here is mine (it included the boxes on the right, is still not including the droppable) : https://jsfiddle.net/7fw86pvk/5/